# Changing Chatter Post Parent from Community

Tags: apex, trigger, community, chatter

## Problem Statement

I need to change the Parent of the Chatter Post (FeedItem) when a specific community user posts a question or poll type post to a Collaboration Group.

### What have I done so far

I have written a trigger to solve the problem stated above, which appears quite simple, however, in the test class I am getting an error when I try to post a **feed** using `System.runAs(CommunityMemberUser)`, I receive **insufficient privileges error.**

---

**Trigger**

```
trigger FeedItemTrg on FeedItem(before Insert)
{
    // get the community id
    Network[] wfCommunity = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Network WHERE Name = 'Workfront Experience' AND Status = 'Live' LIMIT 1];
    Id wfCommunityId = wfCommunity[0].Id;
    for(FeedItem fi: trigger.new)
    {
        // check if the record belongs to community, Question or Poll type, and posted to a user
        if(fi.NetworkScope == wfCommunityId && (fi.Type== 'QuestionPost' || fi.Type=='PollPost') && String.valueOf(fi.ParentId).subString(0, 3) == '005')
        {
            // change the parent to discussion group Id
            fi.ParentId = '[CollborationGroupId]';
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Test class**

```
@isTest static void insertTest()
{
    // query communities
    List<Network> wfCommunity = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Network WHERE Name = 'Workfront Experience' LIMIT 1];
    // find a member of the community
    List<NetworkMember> ntmembers = [SELECT Id, MemberId, Network.Name FROM NetworkMember WHERE NetworkId=: wfCommunity[0].Id LIMIT 1];
    List<User> usr = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id=:ntmembers[0].MemberId];
    // post using member of the community
    System.runAs(usr[0])
    {
        // create a feed item post with with group parent
        FeedItem fi = new FeedItem();
        fi.Title = 'test post';
        fi.ParentId = Userinfo.getUserId();
        fi.Type = 'QuestionPost';
        fi.NetworkScope = wfCommunity[0].Id;
        insert fi;
        // test class behavior with asserts
        fi = [SELECT Id, Type, ParentId, NetworkScope FROM FeedItem WHERE Id=: fi.Id];
        System.assertEquals('QuestionPost', fi.Type);
        System.assertEquals([GROUPID], fi.ParentId);
    }

}
```

---

**Error**

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000339166)

> It is not currently possible to simply re-parent Chatter Feed records
>   or move them from one record to another via an update operation. This
>   is because the FeedItem ParentId field that stores the ID of the
>   object type or record to which the FeedItem is related does not
>   support an update call.  To workaround this limitation, you can
>   recreate the posts and associate them with the new parent record.

Although, I was re-parenting it in `before insert` event, it still did not allow me and gave weird error of **Insufficient Access on cross reference field**. Anyways, after doing debugging and reading above help article, I recreated the post with new Parent in the `after insert` event and it was successfully created with desired ParentId.